# How can I change the default search engine in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, search, search-engine

Safari for OS X only offers three search engines:

- Google, Yahoo, Bing

I want to use https://startpage.com as a default search engine to search directly from the unified URL/search bar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**AnySearch**](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/extensions/#anysearch) *extension* allows you to set any search engine you want.

It achieves it by listening to the `beforeSearch` event, canceling the default behaviour and checking your settings for your chosen search engine. Then it puts your query into the specified search engine and displays the results.

You could, too, edit the `host` file, redirecting form any of the *default* search engines to the one you want, but that wont be so neat.

Comment: This extension is great! I got it to work by using the search key `https://startpage.com/do/search?cat=web&cmd=process_search&language=deutsch&engine0=v1all&query=@@@`.

Comment: Also, thank you for the additional info about the `beforeSearch` event. I was wondering whether the search query would still be transmitted to Google/Yahoo/Bing. That's the whole point of using another default search engine besides the ones given by Safari.