# How to use a custom search engine in Safari?

Tags: safari, search

I am experimenting with a new search engine, https://neera.ai/ and I want to make it my default search engine on Safari. Though Safari doesn't give me an option to specify in a new search engine. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69198/409600 is similar, but the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Comment: Same need here. There are some great search engine options like https://searx.tiekoetter.com and it's crazy that we can't define these in Safari and are stuck with other browsers.

Comment: Same limitation on iOS mobile safari too only showing 5 options. I was hoping to switch to brave search.

Answer (score 3):

It's [been suggested](https://github.com/mcs07/AnySearch-safari-extension#deprecated-safari-no-longer-supports-extensions-that-modify-the-behaviour-of-the-address-bar-consider-using-a-separate-tool-such-as-alfred-httpswwwalfredappcom) that since Apple disallows using other search engines (other than their own sanctioned options and/or the ones that develop Safari extensions), we could use something like this with Safari:

- Alfred: https://www.alfredapp.com/help/features/web-search/custom-searches/ or
- LaunchBar: https://www.obdev.at/resources/launchbar/help/SearchTemplates.html

Recently I saw another option - and I CANNOT vouch for the quality of it, but it seems somewhat well received via reviews is [xSearch for Safari](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xsearch-for-safari/id1579902068). Again, I'm not a user and I cannot say if it's any good, but it seems to be a possible option. I'm guessing there may be other similar extensions out there that I've not yet seen...

Let's hope that Apple finally puts this power back into the hands of its users at some point soon instead of resulting to convoluted options!

Comment: Wow so Apple doesn’t allow arbitrary search engines? There’s no search address text field you could put any website into? On my iPhone there’s just a select group of search engines to choose from as a single selection UI.

Comment: xSearch works great! can replace default search engine in Safari

Answer (score 0):

The free extension [Safari Keyword Search](http://safarikeywordsearch.aurlien.net) lets you assign prefixes to custom search engines like Google Chrome 's built-in [Custom Search Engine](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426) functionality.

So you could assign "n" to Neera.ai, "g" to Google, "duck" to DuckDuckGo, and so on, and per query direct to your search engine as indicated by the prefix.

I use it since 2 years and it works fine. Just occasionally after some Safari updates you may need to run a small [cleanup procedure](https://github.com/arnemart/SafariKeywordSearch#did-the-extension-disappear-from-safari-on-macos).